# When converting Json to Bson Document fails to correctly convert date value

Tags: json.net, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to convert Json Object to MongoDb BsonDocument, however after conversion date valued from Json object is converted to string instead of date. Following examples output BsonValueType as string.
Is there any way to correctly convert to Bson Date value?

```
        var newObject = new JObject {
                             { "name", "John" },
                            { "age", 25 },                                
                            { "registeredDate" , "2017-05-09T09:14:06+00:00"},
        };

        BsonDocument bsonObj = BsonDocument.Parse(newObject.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine(bsonObj["registeredDate"].BsonType);
        //Outputs String
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't too surprising, since your JSON object's `registeredDate` property has a string value to begin with (even though it contains a value that is formatted like an ISO date).

Try one of the following:

- If you want to keep `newObject` as type `JObject`:

  ```csharp
  var newObject = new JObject
  {
      { "name", "John" },
      { "age", 25 },
      { "registeredDate" , new JRaw(@"new ISODate(""2017-05-09T09:14:06+00:00"")") },
  };                    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

  This gives MongoDB's `BsonDocument.Parse` a hint that the string value contains an ISO timestamp and should be converted as a date/time type.
- If you're OK with using a (strongly-typed) anonymous C# type for `newObject` instead:

  ```csharp
  var newObject = new
  {
      name = "John",
      age = 25,
      registeredDate = DateTime.Parse("2017-05-09T09:14:06+00:00"),
  };
  BsonDocument bsonObj = BsonDocument.Parse(newObject.ToJson());
  ```

  This completely takes Json.NET out of the loop and lets MongoDB do all the work.

I admit that I don't know whether these solutions are how things are supposed to be done. I don't know the involved libraries well enough to demonstrate other (and possibly better) options.